# Reflection : How to call dynamic methods based on which object is being send

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to invoke methods on instances of two different classes. I think I want to do this using reflection, but I'm having trouble with that. Here's my code without reflection:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Searcher search = new Searcher();

    String folderToSearch = search.filepath;
    File folder = new File(folderToSearch);
    Set<File> list = new HashSet<File>();

    search.getFiles(folder, list);
    for (File file : list) {
        BruteForceSearch bSearch = new BruteForceSearch(file, toSearch);
        DisplaySearch(toSearch, bSearch);
    }

    System.out.println("\RegEx Search");

    for (File file : list) {
        RegExSearch rSearch = new RegExSearch(file, toSearch);
        DisplaySearch(toSearch, rSearch);
    }
}

private static void DisplaySearch(String toSearch, Object bSearch) {

    int count = 0;

    if (bSearch instanceof BruteForceSearch) {
        BruteForceSearch search = (BruteForceSearch) bSearch;     
    } else if (bSearch instanceof RegExSearch) {
        RegExSearch search = (RegExSearch) bSearch;     
    }

    if ( search.getCount(toSearch) > 0) {
        System.out.printf("%s - %s matches.%n", search.getFile(),
              search.getCount(toSearch));
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        System.out.printf("Empty Result Set");
    }
}
```

I am having trouble in the `DisplaySearch()` method. How can I use reflection here? Or should I just write different methods?

Comment: You're having *what* in the `DisplaySearch` method? Your code won't compile, `search` is used out of scope.

Comment: I added the DisplaySearch  method, it just prints the result

Comment: But it _doesn't_ print the result. It doesn't run at all. As @MaartenBodewes noted, it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call search specific methods in your `if` or `else` code blocks:

```
if (bSearch instanceof BruteForceSearch) {
    BruteForceSearch search = (BruteForceSearch) bSearch;     
} else if (bSearch instanceof RegExSearch) {
    RegExSearch search = (RegExSearch) bSearch;     
}
```

should be:

```
if (bSearch instanceof BruteForceSearch) {
    BruteForceSearch search = (BruteForceSearch) bSearch;
    // perform brute force specific calls, e.g. search.setMaxTimeSeconds(100);
} else if (bSearch instanceof RegExSearch) {
    RegExSearch search = (RegExSearch) bSearch;
    // perform regular expression specific calls
}
```

Currently you are *casting* to a specific searcher class, assign it to a local variable `search` (which holds a reference) and then toss away the variable and reference, leaving you only `bSearch`.

---

If you just want to call `search` on the object then you need to create a interface or abstract class `Searcher` and let both `BruteForceSearch` and `RegExSearch` implement (`implements` for interfaces) or extend (`extends` for classes) it. This is likely what you need to do.

Your method declaration would then be:

```
private static void displaySearch(String toSearch, Searcher searcher) {
    ...
    searcher.search(...);
    ...
}
```

Note that I changed the method to start with a lowercase character.

---

There is no need for explicit reflection here.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to execute different code, depending on the dynamic type of some method argument. There are basically three ways to achieve this:

- The instanceof Operator: you are using it now and for this setting there isn't really anything wrong with it.
- Reflection: obj.getClass() will give you the Class for the Object and you can then get the name of the class (getName()) or check if it is a subtype of an other class (isAssignableFrom()). The last one is basically the same as instanceof but might sometimes be faster as it does not need a null check. Look into the Javadocs for more details.
- You could use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

You cannot use overloaded methods as Java chooses the appropriate method based on the static type of the arguments, not the dynamic types. You can only use that if you know the type at the call site. I'm not completely sure from your code example, but I guess you do not know it.